# Joomla 2.5: update user groups/accesses

Tags: php, joomla, acl

We have access: "`Public`", "`Register`", "`Premium`" and groups "Public", "`Register`", "`Premium`". `Access name = Group name`.

We have material: "`New Article`", that can be viewed only "`Premium`".

We have user "`Foo`", he have access "`Register`" only. He not see "`New Article`".

Now, we give "`Foo`" new group "`Premium`" (and, accordingly, a new access "`Premium`"). But, "`Foo`" does not see "`New Article`". If "`Foo`" logout and again login, he can see.

How I can reset (`cache/session/cookie`?) info about `groups/accesses` for "`Foo`" user? Need he could immediately see the materials, after the appointment of the new groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, need get session user and current user. After update session.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$newUser = new JUser($user->id);

$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('user', $newUser);
```